# Animate ListView item to full screen in Flutter

Tags: animation, flutter

I would like to have my list items perform [this animation](https://material.io/design/navigation/navigation-transitions.html#hierarchical-transitions) ([mp4](https://material.io/design/assets/0B8wSqcLwbhFubWY5ZWNxNjJBVEE/hierarchicaltransitions-1-spec.mp4)) when tapped. I tried using `AnimatedCrossFade` but it requires its two children to be at the same level, e.g. the detail view cross-fades with the ListView not the tapped item. In fact it seems a `Hero` animation is the only one that can animate across widgets.

I'm having trouble using Hero. Should it wrap the list item? Does it matter if the Widget subtree is significantly different in the Hero source/destination? Also, can Hero animations be used with `LocalHistoryRoute`s or [staggered animations](https://flutter.io/animations/staggered-animations/)?

**Edit**

It's now looking like what I need to do is use an `Overlay`, the hard part there is that I need to add the selected item to the overlay at the same position on screen where it was tapped, then the animation part would be easy. Possibly of use here is a target/follower pattern e.g. [`CompositedTransformTarget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CompositedTransformTarget-class.html)

Comment: what do you want to do after the animation? keep it as an open screen that will have future transitions or close it back as an only option?

Comment: Is displaying the fullscreen content into a new route a valid thing in your situation ?

Comment: @RémiRousselet yes

Comment: @JacobPhillips the link for "this animation" and "mp4" links lead to a 404.  Can it be updated? Thanks

Answer (score 38):

You can just use `Hero` widget to make that kind of animation. Here's my example:

[image]

and the source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new FirstPage(title: 'Color Palette'),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  FirstPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => new _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  final palette = [
    {'#E53935': 0xFFE53935},
    {'#D81B60': 0xFFD81B60},
    {'#8E24AA': 0xFF8E24AA},
    {'#5E35B1': 0xFF5E35B1},
    {'#3949AB': 0xFF3949AB},
    {'#1E88E5': 0xFF1E88E5},
    {'#039BE5': 0xFF039BE5},
    {'#00ACC1': 0xFF00ACC1},
    {'#00897B': 0xFF00897B},
    {'#43A047': 0xFF43A047},
    {'#7CB342': 0xFF7CB342},
    {'#C0CA33': 0xFFC0CA33},
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: palette.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => new Hero(
                  tag: palette[index].keys.first,
                  child: new GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator
                          .of(context)
                          .push(new ColorPageRoute(palette[index]));
                    },
                    child: new Container(
                      height: 64.0,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color: new Color(palette[index].values.first),
                      child: new Center(
                        child: new Hero(
                          tag: 'text-${palette[index].keys.first}',
                          child: new Text(
                            palette[index].keys.first,
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.copyWith(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, int> color;

  SecondPage({this.color});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Color'),
      ),
      body: new Hero(
        tag: color.keys.first,
        child: new Container(
          color: new Color(color.values.first),
          child: new Center(
            child: new Hero(
              tag: 'text-${color.keys.first}',
              child: new Text(
                color.keys.first,
                style:
                    Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ColorPageRoute extends MaterialPageRoute {
  ColorPageRoute(Map<String, int> color)
      : super(
            builder: (context) => new SecondPage(
                  color: color,
                ));

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    return FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it needs to cover the appbar as well. hence the overlay

Comment: it's okay if it doesn't I suppose. I do want the elevation part but that can just run before navigating and triggering the hero animation. I need another day or two to try this out.

Comment: What you're doing seems to be close to the example hero animation, which I had working, but when using Hero in my code it always complained of duplicate tag names in the widget tree.

Comment: Could you give me the detail of that complaint?

Comment: `Hero` is the easiest solution. But it has a few problems. Such as being available only with Navigator. Which is a pain in many situations.

Comment: The 'duplicate tag names' issue mentioned above occurs if you have your Hero widget in a ListView. I've not yet found a way of animating from a Hero widget ina ListView to the matching tag Hero widget on another page

Comment: As anticipated when reading this code, I'm getting the error that a Hero cannot be a descendant of another Hero.  Am I doing something wrong or does this code no longer compile with current Dart/Flutter versions?

Answer (score 2):

Someone wrote an amazing dart-package for just this purpose: https://pub.dev/packages/morpheus#-readme-tab-

All you then need to do is use the MorpheusPageRoute and the package handles the rest.

```
...
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MorpheusPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => MyWidget(title: title),
  ),
);
...
```

Comment: Not a updated package

Answer (score 0):

I'd just cheat and wrap the whole thing in a Stack - bottom layer would be a page with the AppBar, and the top layer would be transparent until painted on.

onTap, duplicate ListTile onto the top surface, and then a Hero animation would fill the full screen.  It's not very elegant, but the framework  doesn't (yet) provide for covering the AppBar easily, so having a canvas ready to be painted on for other tricky animations might be resourceful.

Comment: I haven't found a way to duplicate a widget onto an overlay. I could do it if there were a way to get a widget's position on screen. I bet there is but I haven't found it. I should look at the Hero animation source code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to comment or edit Lucas' post (new account) but you also need to provide the parentKey of the widget where the animation is to begin:

```
final widgetKey = GlobalKey();
...
ListTile(
  key: widgetKey,
  title: Text('My ListItem'),
  onTap: () => Navigator.push(
    context,
    MorpheusPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => MyNewPage(),
      parentKey: widgetKey,
    ),
  ),
),
```

https://pub.dev/packages/morpheus